# resize UIImageView at rotation fluidly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an `UIImageView` inside an `UIViewController`. When I rotate the device, in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` i calculate again the frame of UIImageView. But doing so I see the rotation (and resize) of elements built with Interface builder, and after (right, I use DIDrotate) the frame sized correctly. In Photo app the resize is better, fluid. I don't see the resize, but this resize is doing at the same time of rotation.

How can i do?

Comment: are you using autolayout ?

Comment: I have to change the dimension of UIImageView depending of orientation (to change x and y position) and size to keep aspect ration of the image. Can i use autolayot is this case?

Comment: yes you can can you show the image you need ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want

Comment: I've checked "Use auto layout" in IB